# Bottom tabbed view with auto tab change at specific interval

Tags: xamarin, tabs, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin.
I am trying to achieve a functionality of tabbed view at the bottom for the android. In various post, I saw that it is not recommended to have tab bar at the bottom but it is the main requirement from the client. So I am need of this sample example. Also the tabs at the bottom should be auto changed after an interval say 2-3 seconds just like image changes in the gallery. On auto tab change, I need to change the corresponding view/fragment attached to that tab.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  You've just given us a set of requirements.

Comment: Hi Jason, I need to have sample code for this functionality as on internet I am unable to find it. Also My question - Is it fine to have a tab bar at the bottom from the performance point of view.